# Cordova lunch app or unlock screen or wake up screen on android

Tags: android, cordova

im working on an alarm app with cordova and the thing is that i need to wake up the screen. I was looking for some solution but couldnt find one. Could someone tell me what to do ? I know it is possible to at least wake up the screen because the snapchat app has that feature.

I will be greatful if someone will give me even a little hint :)

Comment: how and when do you want to wake up the Screen? by detecting a touch ???

Comment: Well, i thought about setting up a timer. And then when the timer runs out then the screen should turn on. Or the other idea was with local notifications. If the notification triggers then the screen should turn on.